# How to use Simple HTML Dom to get an adjacent sibling element?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple HTML Dom parser to get an element from an HTML string using it's class name, like:

```
foreach ($html->find('div[class=news-div]')) {
    $news = $news-div;
}
```

But I also need to get two elements (one is `span` and the other is `a`) that occur just before the `$news`, but they don't have an `id` that can be predicted because it is calculated dynamically, and they don't have a unique `class` name.

How can I extract the two adjacent elements occurring before `$news-div`?

Comment: simple html dom doesn't support the css next sibling selector (`+`) but [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory) does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SimpleHTML has `prev_sibling` and `next_sibling` methods

```
$elems = $html->find('div[class=news-div]');

foreach ( $elems as $news ) {

    $prev_span = $news->prev_sibling();

    $prev_a    = $prev_span->prev_sibling();

}
```